# pass data from app.js to components in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have defined the customerid in my App.js as follows:

```
const customerid=this.state.userid;
```

I want to pass this customerid value into my customer component.
I call customerid as follows in customer component.

```
const result = await axios.get("https://localhost:44357/api/Orders/CustomerId/${customerid}");
```

How can I passe cutomerid from app.js to customer.js?
Can some genius help me with this?

Comment: This link might help provide further info: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from a parent component (app in this case) to a child component (customer in this case) just use props and access it in the child component.

```
<Child customerid={this.state.userid} />
```

Answer (score 0):

While passing the data to the child component, which in this case is Customer, you just need to pass it as props when calling the Customer component.

```
<Customer customerid={this.state.userid}/>
```